# What's wrong with my gun?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

The error I get is
[ERROR] addons/armory station pack/lua/weapons/money_test.lua:31: attempt to call field 'Create' (a nil value)
  1. unknown - addons/armory station pack/lua/weapons/money_test.lua:31

My gun code is here.

```
SWEP.PrintName      = "Money Test"
SWEP.Author     = "( Justin Yates )"
SWEP.Instructions   = "Left click to make it rain."

SWEP.Spawnable = true
SWEP.AdminSpawnable = true

SWEP.Primary.ClipSize   = -1
SWEP.Primary.DefaultClip  = -1
SWEP.Primary.Automatic    = false
SWEP.Primary.Ammo   = "none"

SWEP.Secondary.ClipSize   = -1
SWEP.Secondary.DefaultClip  = -1
SWEP.Secondary.Automatic  = false
SWEP.Secondary.Ammo   = "none"

SWEP.Weight     = 2
SWEP.AutoSwitchTo   = false
SWEP.AutoSwitchFrom   = false

SWEP.Slot     = 1
SWEP.SlotPos      = 2
SWEP.DrawAmmo     = true
SWEP.DrawCrosshair    = true

SWEP.ViewModel      = "models/weapons/v_pistol.mdl"
SWEP.WorldModel     = "models/weapons/v_hands.mdl"

function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
  local money = ents.Create("spawned_money")
  money:SetPos(self:GetPos())
  money.dt.amount = 500
  money:Spawn()
  money:Activate()
end
```

It does work but spams the console with lua errors.

Comment: http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/ents/Create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your description right. You're getting this error clientside.

`ents.Create()` is a serverside function. To create a clientside entity, you'll need `ents.CreateClientProp()`.

Read up on my GMod (It's been a while, since I programmed GMod Lua..) Try this:

```
function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
  if SERVER then
    local money = ents.Create("spawned_money")
    money:SetPos(self:GetPos())
    money.dt.amount = 500
    money:Spawn()
    money:Activate()
  end
end
```

Comment: Now it says failed to index dt a nil value and no longer drops money

Comment: Hm.. You haven't got any init/cl_init files apart from that one file? (I assume it's a shared file?)